# Perl code not working as intended

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to compare a list of servers registered with spacewalk and the server list in database. The below doesn't print it the server exists in database. The server does exist in database, but it isn't printing it out. Can you please check and let me know as to where I might done a mistake?

```
my @swsrvlist = qx(/bin/spacecmd -q system_list 2>/dev/null);
foreach(@swsrvlist)
{$select1 = "select host from hosts where host = '$_';";
print "running SQL --- " . $select1. " --- against mysql.\n" if $debug;

my $records1 = $dbh->prepare($select1);
$records1->execute;
while (my @data1 = $records1->fetchrow_array) {
print "$data1[0]";
$records1->finish;
}

  }
```

When I do turn on debugging in the script, I get below result.

```
running SQL --- select host from hosts where (host = 'swprxy01.xxxx.com
'); --- against mysql.
 running SQL --- select host from hosts where (host = 'bldtest10.xxxx.com
'); --- against mysql.
```

Comment: One word - `chomp` (right after `foreach`).

Comment: That should be it. Thank you, Raina.

Comment: @raina77ow please post that as an answer so Kevin M can accept it and the question doesn't show as unanswered. Thanks.